# Selecting checkbox from HTMLRowElement jquery

Tags: jquery

$('#alarmTable tr').each(function(key, value)

This statement returns me rows of the table. For each row, I need to find the cell containing the checkbox and see whether it is checked or not. How can I do it?

Comment: `$('#alarmTable tr td')` will give you all the cells. `$('#alarmTable tr td .checkbox')` will give you all the checkbox inside the `td` inside the `tr` inside `#alarmTable`. Replace `.checkbox` with your identifier for cehckbox.

Comment: You should post your markup to make answering easier.

Comment: $('#alarmTable tr').each(function(key, value)
          {
           var values1 = $('value td :checkbox:checked');
           alert(values1);
          });   

I am trying this and it's not working. P.S : I am new to jquery